# How to customize cardview?

Tags: android, customization, android-cardview

how can i customize cardview in such a way (the top left one)?

In my way, if i add 3 corored boxes (blue, gray, white) i always get a thin border on the perimeter of the cardview box.
Any example?
Thanks.

[image: Example]

Comment: I think it is not possible with `cardview`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try with relative layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:id="@+id/card_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="230dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cardMarginVertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/cardMarginHorizontal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/cardMarginHorizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cardMarginVertical"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                        app:cardElevation="2dp"
                        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                        app:contentPadding="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                <!--Circle image View-->
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
                        android:id="@+id/circleViewDiscount"
                        android:src="@drawable/border_white"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="10.19\nSaturday\n 30th August 2015"
                        android:textSize="23dp"
                        android:textColor="#08ec38"
                        android:id="@+id/textViewPirceTag"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:margin_Top="50dp" <!--Style the height-->
            android:orientation="horizontal"> 
                    <!--Add element here-->
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>    
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>    
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Pleasure to help @SERG , And I forget to tell you for the circle image you need to compile "compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1" in your gradle